# Подскажите хороший оптимизатор CSS кода?

Tags: css

Оптимизировать вручную несколько десятков килобайт CSS нет желания, хотелось бы, чтобы он делал нечто подобное...

На входе:

```
.class1{
width:100%;
}
.class2{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.class3{
width:100%;
margin:0;
}
```

И на выходе:

```
.class1,
.class2,
.class3{
width:100%;
}
.class2{
height:100%;
}
.class3{
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: откройте для себя [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) и [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). и такая "оптимизация" как вы хотите - плохая затея.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Яндекса есть очень мощный инструмент - [CSSO](http://ru.bem.info/tools/csso/description/). Рекомендую попробовать.

Answer (score 0):

[Оптимизатор CSS](http://wm-tools.net/cssoptimize)